# Enterprise Architect - Printing to PDF shows empty diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using EA version 10 (the latest one). As I print the domain diagram to a PDF, it shows the diagram without any text. Does anyone knows how to fix that? or is it a bug in EA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the PDF generator of EA is now functioning properly. Once I installed Adobe Acrobate Pro X1, I could print the diagram as PDF using the normal printing dialoge.